How to Measure Key Press Pressure in React Native?
I want to measure the pressure or force applied when a user presses any alphabet on the keyboard in a React Native application. Is there a way to detect the pressure of a key press in React Native?
I'm looking for solutions or libraries that can help with this. Any guidance or code examples would be appreciated.
Thank you in advance!
I want to measure the pressure or force applied when a user presses any alphabet on the keyboard in a React Native application. I couldn't find a direct API or library in React Native that supports this feature.
I tried using the onKeyPress event on the TextInput component, but it only detects which key is pressed and doesn't provide any information about the pressure or force of the key press. I also explored gesture-handling libraries like react-native-gesture-handler, but they seem to focus on touch gestures rather than keyboard interactions.
I was expecting a way to capture the pressure (similar to a "force touch" on iOS devices) during keyboard input. Does React Native or any library provide support for this functionality? If not, is there a workaround to achieve it?
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!
